# Using Jacoco with Rest Assured with Java and Gradle for Code Coverage

Tags: gradle, cucumber, code-coverage, rest-assured, jacoco

I have written some Rest Assured API test in Java using Cucumber framework and now I want to see code coverage using Jacoco. How do I do that? I am using Gradle Builder with groovy.

I have added

```
plugins{
    id 'jacoco'
}

jacoco{
    toolVersion = '0.8.10'
}

finalizedBy jacocoTestReport//in test{}
```

Now in build folder it just made a empty folder with name Jacoco. Did I miss something? Please help

Answer (score 0):

The [docs](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/jacoco_plugin.html) suggest slightly different format of build.gradle file.

Try it this way:

```
test {
  finalizedBy jacocoTestReport // report is always generated after tests run
}
jacocoTestReport {
        dependsOn test // tests are required to run before generating the report
}
```